# Get all data from the object into one two-dimentional array

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to dump all data from the object into two-dimetional array

this is the declaration:

```
GetItemCall oGetItemCall = new GetItemCall(oContext);
```

then, I can use `oGetItemCall.Item.ConditionID` or `oGetItemCall.Item.ListingDetails.EndTime` etc.

But the `oGetItemCall` object has lots of variables and I want to add them into one easy to read 2-dimensional array. 
Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is required?
Why don't use a more flexible structure, like list. So try to convert object to list. A [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) can be easily accessed through indexes: in this case through the object's properties names.
[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) can solve the problem.
Have a look [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-reflection-to-get-object-information).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would want to do that, however either one of those should do.

```
        string[,] some = new string[100,2]; 
        Hashtable table = new Hashtable(); 

        // array
        some[0,0] = "Key";
        some[0,1] = "value";

        //  hashtable 
        table["key"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to look at the item and all of it's properties and values?  Use reflection.

It is not perfect and by no means complete - but will give you a good starting point if this is what you want.  Easily extendible to add type names, etc.

```
public static List<string> ReflectObject(object o)
{
    var items = new List<string>();

    if (o == null)
    {
        items.Add("NULL"); // remove if you're not interested in NULLs.
        return items;
    }

    Type type = o.GetType();

    if (type.IsPrimitive || o is string)
    {
        items.Add(o.ToString());
        return items;
    }

    items.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", " ----- ", type.Name));

    if (o is IEnumerable)
    {
        IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)o;
        var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            foreach (var innerItem in ReflectObject(enumerator.Current))
            {
                items.Add(innerItem);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(o, null);

            foreach (var innerItem in ReflectObject(value))
            {
                items.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", property.Name, innerItem));
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.MyProperty1 = 123;
t.MyProperty2 = "hello";
t.MyProperty3 = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };
t.MyTestProperty = new Test();
t.MyTestProperty.MyProperty1 = 987;
t.MyTestProperty.MyTestProperty = new Test();
t.MyTestProperty.MyTestProperty.MyProperty2 = "goodbye";

var items = MyReflector.ReflectObject(t);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This would result in:

```
----- Test -----
MyProperty1: 123
MyProperty2: hello
MyProperty3:  ----- List`1 -----
MyProperty3: one
MyProperty3: two
MyTestProperty:  ----- Test -----
MyTestProperty: MyProperty1: 987
MyTestProperty: MyProperty2: NULL
MyTestProperty: MyProperty3: NULL
MyTestProperty: MyTestProperty:  ----- Test -----
MyTestProperty: MyTestProperty: MyProperty1: 0
MyTestProperty: MyTestProperty: MyProperty2: goodbye
MyTestProperty: MyTestProperty: MyProperty3: NULL
MyTestProperty: MyTestProperty: MyTestProperty: NULL
```